# IOS 7 Power Drain

Tags: ios, power

What settings minimize power loss on a 4S?  I upgraded to IOS 7 and have noticed a signiicant power drain

Comment: General things are: turn off things like Background App Refresh, Push, Location Services.  With maybe a few important exceptions carefully chosen because you absolutely need them.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on what exactly you desire? Are you looking for a comprehensive overview on how to save battery, or something else in particular? If it helps, [Apple has a page about iPhone batteries](http://www.apple.com/batteries/iphone.html).

Answer (score 1):

*I have an iPhone 4S running iOS 7 and these suggestions are based on my experiences with it.*

Background App Refresh is a great new feature in iOS 7 which substantially reduces your battery life. The best way to reclaim that battery life is by restricting that feature to only the apps that absolutely need it.

### Where to find it:

Go the the Settings app, then go to "General" and then "Background App Refresh".

### Start from Zero

My recommendation? Turn off *everything.* Yeah, I know it stinks to lose the functionality, but give yourself a couple of days without it to get a sense of how long your iPhone lasts without them on. It did this and was amazed how much longer my batter was lasting.

Set yourself a calendar reminder for +1 week to go back in and turn on just the ones you feel like you absolutely need/want. I did that too, and also made sure that my iPhone is plugged in when I am at my desk.

### Other Battery Life Tips

Other than that, your battery *should* be pretty much the same as iOS 6. If that still doesn't help enough, try turning down the screen brightness to about 75% unless you are somewhere where you need to have it higher.

Macworld did a good article (pre-iOS 7, however) about facts vs myths in iOS battery savings http://www.macworld.com/article/2046209/fact-or-fiction-nine-iphone-and-ipad-battery-saving-techniques-tested.html